Create Outlook Web mailItem using Excel VBA
I am trying to send an Outlook Web email using MS Outlook 15.0 object library and VBA codes from host Excel 2013.
When the macro tries to create MailItem, Microsoft asks me to open Outlook 2013 account. Is this necessary?
Is there any solution?

Microsoft Outlook Object Library requires the desktop version.  VBA does not run on the web.

I don't see why VBA couldn't access outlook through a web browser but it isn't going to do so using the outlook object model as that assumes you're working in the outlook desktop application, you'll need to write the framework for accessing it through a browser.

I use this code, which uses powershell in the end.
Sub mailversand(tovar As String, betreff As String, mailbody As String, bccmax As Boolean, Optional attachm As String)
On Error GoTo ende

Dim fehlerzeile As Integer
   Dim fileToSend  As String, fromvar As String, server As String, commandzeile As String, anrede_re As String, port As String

   fileToSend = "\\myserver\temp\mail_auftragseingang.html"

If (Dir(fileToSend) <> "") Then Kill fileToSend
Call textdatei_erstellen(fileToSend, mailbody)

   fromvar = "noreply.whatever@domain.at "
   server = "vpn.domain.at"
   port = 25
   betreff = "'" & betreff & "'"

   commandzeile = "send-mailmessage -From " & fromvar & " -Encoding ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8) -To " & tovar & " -Subject " & betreff & _
           " -SmtpServer " & server & " -Port " & port

        If attachm <> "" Then commandzeile = commandzeile & " -Attachments '" & attachm & "'"
         If mailbody <> "" Then commandzeile = commandzeile & " -body (get-content -path " & fileToSend & ") -BodyAsHtml"
        If bccmax = True Then commandzeile = commandzeile & " -BCC mybccaddress@domain.at"
 
    commandzeile = "powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command " & Chr$(34) & commandzeile & Chr$(34)
    Debug.Print commandzeile
    Shell commandzeile, vbHide ' Use vbNormalFocus to show the PowerShell console
           
ende:
If Err <> 0 Then MsgBox("Err-Nr: " & Err.Number & Chr(10) & "Err-Desc: " & Err.Description & Chr(10) & "Err-Source: " & Err.Source & Chr(10) & "Sub Mailversand" & Chr(10) & Now())
End Sub

Function textdatei_erstellen(strPath, textzeile)
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oFile As Object
Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(Replace(strPath, "/", "-"))
oFile.WriteLine textzeile
oFile.Close
Set fso = Nothing
Set oFile = Nothing
End Function

I call that sub with
Sub test_mv()
Call mailversand("max.mad@testing.com", "test text", "supi dubi lsdfj sldkfj säö üsdfü    äääüüüßßß #aá è  ", False)
End Sub

you might want to change the error-handling. But this is far easier then using outlook, and there is no way to use outlook-web with VBA as far as I know.
Max

Hi Max   the Sub Mailversand runtime error  when reading
Dir(fileToSend) <> ""
Err-Nr: 52
Err-Desc: file Name or Number incorrect

What have you put instead of fileToSend = "\myserver\temp\mail_auftragseingang.html"? You can either put a unc-path like in my example or something "like C:\test.txt"

Hi Logon did you get that running? Would be great to seee if it works for you.
